# How to make a 2D domain from 1D domains in Chapel

Tags: chapel

In order to keep my matrices `A` in sync with my vectors `v` I want to create

```
var vdom: domain(1) = {1...10},
    mdom: domain(2) = {odom, odom};
```

However, this gives me a compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domains are initialized with [ranges](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/builtins/internal/ChapelRange.html). So you need to build `mdom` from `vdom`'s ranges, by calling the [`dim(i)`](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html#ChapelArray.dim) method:

```
var vdom: domain(1) = {1...10},
    mdom: domain(2) = {odom.dim(1), odom.dim(1)};
```

It is also a common pattern to define the problem space as a range, and then re-use that variable elsewhere:

```
const vectorSpace = 1..10;
var vdom = {vectorSpace},
    mdom = {vectorSpace, vectorSpace};
```

Comment: guess the `{ odom.dim(1), odom.dim(1) }` ought actually read **`vdom...`**

Comment: In trying this, I noticed that if `vdom` changes, then `mdom` does not.  I'd like to tie them together.

Comment: I assume you want to tie them together such that a domain resize impacts both arrays... AFAIK, that's not possible in Chapel today.